# Is Land of the Lustrous inspired by James Cameron's Avatar?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, analysis

Let's look at the similar plots of these films:

[image: a column row consisting of similar plot]

Phos and Cinnabar (first image) have similar story roles to Jake and Neytiri from *Avatar* (second image):

[image: Phos and Cinnabar from Land of the Lustrous]

[image: Jake and Neytiri from Avatar]

While *Avatar* is a sci-fi space story, and *Land of the Lustrous* is a fantasy adventure anime, both take place on an alien planet with different species.

The stories begin similarly:

- In *Avatar* Jake is a newcomer to Pandora and meets the alien Neytiri. She doesn't seem to get along with Jake at first, but later on they become lovers.
- In *Land of the Lustrous* Phosphophyllite or Phos meets a fellow Gem named Cinnabar, a toxic humanoid that releases mercury. Cinnabar still doesn't get along with Phos until now, but in the rest of the episodes, Phos and Cinnabar are somehow getting along in a respectful manner.

They have similar endings:

- In *Avatar*, Neytiri saved Jake from Col. Quaritch and puts a gas mask on Jakes's face, allowing him to breathe properly again.
- In *Land of the Lustrous*, Cinnabar flooded the whole Lunarians and beheaded the last Lunarian that was attempting to stop Phos.

So is Phos based on Jake, and Cinnabar based on Neytiri?

Are they coincidentally similar? *Avatar* came out in 2009 and *Land of the Lustrous* was released in 2017-2018. While they have different directors and authors, the stories of these films are somehow similar.

Comment: Please do not post a table as an image. Markdown makes it easy to construct a table: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables , https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#tables , etc. Text in images is not searchable.

Comment: Note that *Avatar* is, in turn, striking similar to Disney's *Atlantis: The Lost Empire*. I've also heard comparisons to *Dances with Wolves* but, having never seen it, I can't say how accurate they are.

Comment: I've gone through and tried to clear up your grammar somewhat, but I have to admit that I had no idea what you were trying to say in certain places. If you feel I've misunderstood what you were trying to say, or edited out something important, feel free to [edit] it again.

Comment: @F1Krazy Avatar is _Dance with Wolves in space_, even James Cameron himself admitted it https://www.latimes.com/archives/blogs/hero-complex-blog/story/2009-08-14/james-cameron-yes-avatar-is-dances-with-wolves-in-space-sorta

Answer (score 1):

While the Manga came out in October 2012, *Haruko Ichikawa* had somehow seen the movie in 2010s, but it was never said she had draw all of the ideas from the movie, Despite working in the early production, she had spent on working all the drawing and sketches side by side even with the scripts.

So it's either that the Anime was somehow influenced by the Movie.

Comment: Seems fantastic! i hadn't finished reading the manga since the animation is way accurate to see the scenes and it's beautiful

Comment: @UrssCH i read it in a magazine a long time ago, i also seen it many times from now. Despite the movie is a science fiction while the anime is a Fantasy from another planet, Yeah.